# Indexing in Neo4j 2.0

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j2.0.Suppose I have 25000 items with label "RECORD" and they have a property which is a number. I want to index all these 25000 items, so that my range queries become faster. By range queries, I mean, if I want to find all items of type RECORD and whose value indexed property value lies in a certain range.

This is what I did to achieve indexing. is this correct or not.

```
`IndexDefinition def = service.schema().indexFor(records).on("Date").create();`
```

After creation of index, I just created the nodes like this.

```
`Node a = service.createNode(record) ;`
```

If I keep on creating all my 25000 nodes like this, are they indexed automatically? Will I achieve speed in my queries by doing this? I am just worried about that there might be some things else that need be done to actually get the indexing effect of the 
line:

```
IndexDefinition  def = service.schema().indexFor(records).on("Date").create();
```

Answer (score 0):

To smartly index your numeric attributes for range queries, you can make use of Valuecontext . Refer [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html)
Indexing will definitely speed up your queries .